# is there a way I could display a variable from JavaScript onto html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a variable from an extension called node temp mail
its just a temp email generator
i installed it using npm
tell me if you want some more info I am new to webdev

i want the variable `body` to display in the html or on the website itself

**Here‘s the code:**

```js
var TempMail = require('node-temp-mail');

function makeid(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}

var address = new TempMail(makeid(5),true);

address.fetchEmails(function(err,body){
    console.log(body);
});

address.getAddress()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="javasquript.js"></script>
    <title>Debit Card Design</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="card">
        <h4 class="bank">lightning <span>BANK</span></h4>
        <div class="number">
            <h6>4512</h6>
            <h6>8963</h6>
            <h6>7845</h6>
            <h6>3542</h6>
        </div>
        <img src="img/lightning.png" alt="" class="lightning">
        <img src="img/wave.png" alt="" class="wave">
        <div class="ex_date">
            <span>VALID<br>UPTO</span>
            <h3>02 <span>/</span> 29</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="cvv">
            <span>CVC</span>
            <h1>563</h1>
        </div>
        <img src="img/visa.png" alt="" class="visa">
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="javasquript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it `body` or `address.getAddress()` or both you want shown in html? And how does the data look. Where in the html do you want it shown. Have you made an attempt to solve this, please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an empty div in html Like this:

```html
<div id="address"></div>
```

and then in js you just set the content of the div like this:

```js
document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = body;
```

Please note that this will always override everything contained in the div.

Also, by default *require* is not a valid function. You need to use require.js in order for it to work, so add this in the html:

```html
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js"></script>
```

**Here‘s an example with all things i mentioned implemented:**

```js
var TempMail = require('node-temp-mail');

function makeid(length) {
    var result           = '';
    var characters       = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    var charactersLength = characters.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return result;
}

var address = new TempMail(makeid(5),true);

address.fetchEmails(function(err,body){
    document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = body;
});

address.getAddress();
```

```html
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/minified/require.js"></script>

<div class="card">
    <h4 class="bank">lightning <span>BANK</span></h4>
    <div class="number">
        <h6>4512</h6>
        <h6>8963</h6>
        <h6>7845</h6>
        <h6>3542</h6>
    </div>
    <img src="img/lightning.png" alt="" class="lightning">
    <img src="img/wave.png" alt="" class="wave">
    <div class="ex_date">
        <span>VALID<br>UPTO</span>
        <h3>02 <span>/</span> 29</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="cvv">
        <span>CVC</span>
        <h1>563</h1>
    </div>
    <img src="img/visa.png" alt="" class="visa">
    <div id="address"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: excuse me but could you recommend me a what variable I should put for it to work I cant find the right one.

Comment: You want to display `adress.getAdress()` right? Then just replace `yourVariableName` with `adress.getAdress()`

Comment: there is an error saying uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined and this crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

Comment: The require in line 1 has nothing to do with this solution. Is this error new?

Comment: yea its kinda new and thanks for the answer

Comment: oh this poped up now Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: document is not defined

Comment: @HiruyMetsihafe i edited the solution to fix the require error. now everything should work!

Answer (score 0):

Using `innerHTML` has [disadvantages](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/disadvantages-of-using-innerhtml-in-javascript). Maybe better to use [`insertAdjacentElementHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML). Demo:

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `demo`) {
    document.querySelector(`#insert`)
      .insertAdjacentHTML(`beforeend`, `<div>inserted: ${generateUUID()}</div>`);
  }
}

function generateUUID() {
  let [ d, d2, template, replaceLambda ] = [ 
      +new Date(),
      (window.performance && performance.now()*1000) || 0, 
      `00000000-0000-4000-1000-000000000000`,
      chr => {
        let r = Math.random() * 16;
        let rr = d > 0 ? (d + r) % 16 | 0 : (d2 + r) % 16 | 0;
        d > 0 && ( d = ~~(d / 16)) ||  ( d2 = ~~(d2 / 16) );
        return (!+chr ? rr : (rr & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
      }, ];
  
  return template.replace( /[01]/g, replaceLambda );
}
```

```html
<button id="demo">Insert UID</button>
<div id="insert"></div>
```